# error sencha app build native

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-build

i have an error when build `sencha` touch app to `android`.

[ERR] The following **error** occurred while executing this line:

> /opt/lampp/htdocs/simponi/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:435: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/simponi/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:17: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/simponi/.sencha/app/phonegap-impl.xml:109: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/simponi/.sencha/app/phonegap-impl.xml:185: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   jar:file:/home/wahyu/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.3.61/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:668:
>   shellscript returned: 1`

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Can you add the whole error stack trace specifically containing the [INF] part?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but with cordova.

With the -d option in `sencha build app` command, I found that you can not use an application name with spaces.

That's because in the `.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml` file, the target `cordova-create` the `${app.cordova.config.name}` variable is not wrapped by quotes:

```
cordova ${cordova.cli.options} create "${app.cordova.config.path}" ${app.cordova.config.id} ${app.cordova.config.name}
```

To fix this, simply wrap with quotes:

```
cordova ${cordova.cli.options} create "${app.cordova.config.path}" "${app.cordova.config.id}" "${app.cordova.config.name}"
```

In my case my application name was "CBN Salvador" in `app.json` file, in cordova settings.